# netbeans project properties not showing installed glassfish

Tags: netbeans, glassfish-3

im using netbeans 7.3.1. i  installed glassfish 3.1.2.2 because glassfish 4 requires at least jdk 1.7 , and i cant upgrade to jdk1.7 because im on mac os snow leopard and it requires at least os lion.

on netbeans, i have added glassfish 3.1.2.2 and it is showing under

> services tab->servers

when i

> right-click my projects -> properties -> run

i can't select glassfish 3.1.2.2 under server dropdown list.

why is this so, and how can i fix this??

Answer (score 0):

i discover that i was using java ee 7 which doesn't support glassfish 3.1.2.2.